# rotating wheel while executing backend code asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to put a rotating wheel popup on the page while I am executing backend code for fetching new data from DB.
Here is what I tried, but it doesn't want to work so far, nothing gets displayed.
I want to display something when the checkbox is clicked (CheckedChanged), that's when something is fetching from db.

Here is the ajax code I have:

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

                    <Triggers>
                       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="cbAll" eventname="CheckedChanged" />
                    </Triggers>

                    <ContentTemplate>
                    </ContentTemplate>

                 </asp:UpdatePanel>



<asp:updateprogress associatedupdatepanelid="UpdatePanel1"
    id="updateProgress" runat="server">
    <progresstemplate>
        <div id="progressBackgroundFilter"></div>
        <div id="processMessage"> Loading...<br /><br />
             <img alt="Loading" src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </div>
    </progresstemplate>
</asp:updateprogress>
```

And here is the checkbox control:

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="cbAll" runat="server" Checked="true" Text="Show me everything" ForeColor="White"
        Visible="false" AutoPostBack="True" 
        oncheckedchanged="cbAll_CheckedChanged" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code a bit.

You do not need the trigger, the event has AutoPostBack checkbox.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <%--<Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cbAll" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
        </Triggers>--%>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbAll" runat="server" Checked="true" Text="Show me everything"
                ForeColor="White" Visible="false" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="cbAll_CheckedChanged" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" ID="updateProgress" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div id="progressBackgroundFilter">
            </div>
            <div id="processMessage">
                Loading...<br />
                <br />
                <img alt="Loading" src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" />
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this in the past by skipping the update progress control and instead handling the `PageRequestManager` beginRequest and endRequest events.  In my case I also wanted to block the ui of the page, so I used the [jQuery blockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) plugin.

Put the following div somewhere at the root of your page:

```
<div id="processMessage">
    Loading...
    <br />
    <br />
    <img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" />
</div>
```

And style it with the following css:

```
#updatingDiv
{
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    border: solid 1px #AAAAEE;
}
```

Add the following JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(function() {
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#updatingDiv'), css: { border: 'none', background: 'transparent'} });
    });
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function() {
        $.unblockUI();
    });
});
```

You'll need to be sure to include the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library and the blockUI plugin I mentioned earlier.

Of course, you can modify the css/html to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and don t forget the script manager blog.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

    <Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="cbAll" eventname="CheckedChanged" />
    </Triggers>

    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:updateprogress associatedupdatepanelid="UpdatePanel1" id="updateProgress" runat="server">
            <progresstemplate>
            <div id="progressBackgroundFilter"></div>
            <div id="processMessage"> Loading...<br /><br />
             <img alt="Loading" src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" />
            </div>
            </progresstemplate>
        </asp:updateprogress> 
    </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`

.divWaiting
    {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-align: center;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 40%;

```
}

.divWaiting #div1
{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: White;
  width: 180px;
  left: 460px;
  border: 2px solid #870307;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;

}
```

Download .gif image for rotating wheel